# SIP Servlets 2.1.547 Download

Tags: restcomm, sip-servlet

I'm trying to download the latest stable release from https://github.com/RestComm/sip-servlets/releases/tag/v2.1.547 but it appears the link is broken. Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new release should be out shortly but you can use https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestcommSipServlets-Release or https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestcommSipServlets-4.X-Release in the meanwhile

Comment: Well, here's the thing: I've been assigned to find an open-source SIP Servlet alternative to Mobicents, since it was soon to end support. I found Restcomm and it looked good but very similar to Mobicents. And that got me thinking, are they the same? So what I really want to know is, is Restcomm going to end as well, what's with Mobicents? Thank you.

Comment: Mobicents got rebranded to Restcomm about a year ago. It's an evolution not an end, you can read more at https://telestax.com/restcomm-developer-mobicents/

Comment: Now that's really helpful, thanks a lot. I've been trying to figure it out for days. Every time I saw something to prove it, I saw another thing that suggests the exact opposite. It is really comforting to hear this from someone commissioned.